# Column that outputs a number but I am trying to have it output a name depending on what number it is

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to place a column next to `CREATEDATBRANCH` that shows a name instead of a number. How can I do that?

This is my SQL query so far:

```
SELECT [PARENTACCOUNT]
  ,[ID]
  ,[TYPE]
  ,[ORIGINALDATE]
  ,[OPENDATE]
  ,[CHARGEOFFDATE]
  ,[CLOSEDATE]
  ,[PURPOSECODE]
  ,BALANCE AS 'Current Balance'  
  ,[ORIGINALBALANCE]
  ,[CHARGEOFFTYPE]
  ,[CHARGEOFFAMOUNT]
  ,[DESCRIPTION]
  ,[MATURITYDATE]
  ,[BRANCH]
  ,[CREATEDBYUSER]
  ,[CREATEDATBRANCH]
FROM 
    [dbo].[LOAN]
WHERE
    OPENDATE BETWEEN '2023-09-01' AND '2023-09-30' 
    AND CLOSEDATE IS NULL;
```

I tried to use this code but it does not include it in my query, instead it creates it as another result.

```
SELECT
    CREATEDATBRANCH,
    CASE
        WHEN CREATEDATBRANCH = 0 THEN 'Special'
        ELSE CAST(LOAN.CREATEDATBRANCH AS varchar(4))
    END AS 'Location'
FROM
    LOAN;
```

Comment: which table has all branches, this you join with CREATEDATBRANCH and then you have all coumns fron that table

Comment: What's the error or bad result?

Comment: @TheImpaler his problem is simply he want CREATEDATBRANCH (int) the name of the brach behhind CREATEDATBRANCH

Comment: Just add your case expression as another column in your first query. `select col1, col2, col3... your case expression as location from loan`

Comment: And `AS 'Location'` is invalid SQL. In standard SQL that would be `AS "Location"` and in SQL Server `AS [Location]`.

Comment: To me it is not clear what you want. Your `CASE` expressions returns 'Special for createdatbranch 0, and the number of createdatbranch otherwise. Is this what you want or not? If not, what else do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Take just the `CASE` expression from the second query and include it at the end of the `SELECT` list in the first query.

But really, I'd leave this adjustment for client code or the reporting tool.